# What effect would a positron source have on a superconductor's electron flow?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superconductivity

Let's say you have current flowing through a superconductor placed close to a steady source of positrons. What effect would the positrons have on the current?  Would the positrons annihilate some of the electrons, reducing the current?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Positron sources are either β+  nuclear sources, where the postirons are radially emitted incoherently, or coherent beams of postitrons in  accelerators.

Supeconductors need very cold temperatures in order to be superconducting. Depending on the strength of the isotope source, any radiation hitting a superconducting wire will end up in raising locally the temperature and breaking supeconductivity.

With beams it is worse, whether positron or other particles the damage would be the same, overheating, breaking the current, and depending on the power delivered even  explosions, as  modeled in [this paper](https://www.osti.gov/scitech/servlets/purl/81090) for proton beams .  There have been [similar accidents.](https://accelconf.web.cern.ch/accelconf/abdwhb06/PAPERS/WEAZ04.PDF)